# Unable to load Snowflake tables into R

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The issue I am having is such that whenever I run a limit above 500 I get the "R Session Aborted" popup and my session is terminated.

Note: The 500 number seems to vary as I can also do up to 699 at times.

Some Laptop Specifications :

Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz   2.30 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.7 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

```
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(odbc)

myconn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
Driver = "SnowflakeDSIIDriver",
Server = "MYSERVER.snowflakecomputing.com",
Database = "MY_DATABASE",
Schema = "SCHEMA",
Uid="USER",
Pwd="PASS",
Warehouse = "MY_WH")

monthly_table <- DBI::dbGetQuery(myconn, "SELECT * FROM MY_DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE limit 500")
```

The above shows my code.

Edit: From reviewing the driver logs (suggested in the comments by @aek) between a limit (here meaning limit on the row count) that runs and one that does not, in the failed logs there seems to be a

"OCSP Response not found in the cache" message that occurs

Comment: You could try running the SnowCD (Connectivity Diagnostic) tool : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd to see if it finds any issues.  When a result set size gets beyond a certain scale the data is returned via a different mechanism under the hood, from blob storage.  You may be missing required network config/settings to reach that.  Brief explanation here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/hostname-allowlist

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, on attempt it says all checks passed.

Comment: @mcastro R uses Snowflake ODBC driver. Since the error you are getting from R is not really informative, you can enable the driver logs and examine them. See the [doc](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#ODBC) how to do this. If you find any errors in the logs, post it in your question.

Comment: @mcastro can you try running the above code from the R console, i.e. outside of RStudio.  I don't think it's an RStudio related issue, but this might narrow it down, and we may get additional error message.

Comment: @aek thanks for the suggestion, Edit added to reflect what was found in the logs.

Comment: @Fieldy Thanks for this as well, I tried this and it just crashes when running without an additional message

Comment: @mcastro the message you posted just tells that there is no OCSP response in the driver cache, next lines in the log should show how it downloads the OCSP response. I do not think it is related to this issue. Could you check the odbc_generic file? Does it have any errors after R crashed?

Comment: @aek There wasnt an error, however, the url after the sf::ResultChunkDownloaderArrow::getNextChunkToConsume: Next result chunk, url leads to a page with a error. The xml message portion says  "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method"

Comment: @mcastro are you working on windows?

Comment: @mcastro The message `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method` could have multiple root causes, if your SnowCD runs fine and no errors are reported and you know you have no proxy in between, I would suggest you open a case with Snowflake support. What version of ODBC are you using?

Comment: Forgot to update this, thanks to everyone that helped out. The issue as it turns out seems to stem from the newest version of the Snowflake ODBC driver (version 2.25.11). Downloading an older version allows for everything to run smoothly

Comment: Welcome to SO mcastro. This site encourages users to answer their own questions if they find a solution. As such, I encourage you to answer your question rather than commenting. Doing so means if someone else encounters this issue, they won't have to dig through all the comments to find your solution. Many thanks.